# Can't change .Css file for VueJs plugin

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using **[vue-js-modal](https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal/blob/master/README.md)** plugin, And inside this plugin, there is a `style.css` file. In this file, I need to change some setting to customize the changes in the modal style. But when I access this file and change whatever I want and then save my changes and run the application, the modal page look like the previous style and setting! And when I opened the console and checked the elements and select the modal page, the style setting in the browser it's the same previous setting! How can I solve this problem? Do I need to build the file contains the `style.css`? If yes, how can I build it? If no, how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Deep Selector in you vue app to rewrite modal css
https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors

for me syntax is following

```
/deep/ p {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes I used it and it is work, but when I try to override the specific class, the other properties are changes .. like I want to change the border-radius of the modal to 25px, so I only change for that class .. unfortunately, the background becomes white outside the modal box, and before it was semi-transparent. here the style file: https://github.com/euvl/vue-js-modal/blob/master/dist/styles.css

Answer (score 1):

Why not override the CSS rules you want to change, either in your own CSS file or in the `style` tag if you're using single-file components?

Comment: When I do it inside the modal by using style tag to change `border-radius`, the background border radius change not the modal box .. that's why I try to change it in the original CSS file of the plugin. when I view the modal in the browser and change the border-radius from the CSS in the browser it changes! so why in the original CSS file not change?

Comment: You're right that there may be a build step required for the CSS in the plugin files to apply. I would suggest adding an ID to the modal component in your template and using that to make sure your rule takes priority.

Comment: You mean adding id for the modal, and use this id to change the style via it? And how to build it to apply the changes? I need the steps.

Answer (score 1):

A quick fix would be to change the version of the css file by adding to the path of the file.

Old: "/mycssfile.css"

New: "/mycssfile.css?1"

Comment: why should I change its name?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. it will force all clients to download the new version, which could be what is preventing you from loading the new css file. the questionmark and the numbers that follow specify the version number of the css file.